# Is it possible to refactor this SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

I have the following code, but would prefer not to refer to the table @test and its basic where clause more than once, I have tried refactoring it with ROWCOUNT, but cannot solve it.

```
select * 
from @test2
where userid = @userid
    and (
        ExpiryDate > getdate() 
            or 
        not exists(select * from @test2 
                       where userid = @userid 
                         and ExpiryDate > Getdate() 
                         and Status = 40)
        )
```

This is the data I'm using for testing:

```
declare @test2 table(ID int, ExpiryDate datetime, userid int, siteid int, Status int)
insert into @test2 (ID, ExpiryDate, userid, siteid, Status)
--not expired/status=40 and not status=40 entries
select 1, '2013-08-16', 1, 1, 40
union
select 2, '2013-08-16', 1, 1, 10
union
--not expired/status=40 and status=40 entries
select 3, '2013-08-16', 2, 2, 40 
union
select 4, '2013-08-16', 2, 2, 40
union
--expired/status=40 and not status=40 entries
select 5, '2013-08-13', 3, 3, 40
union
select 6, '2013-08-16', 3, 3, 10
union
--expired/status=40 and status=40 entries
select 7, '2013-08-13', 4, 4, 40
union
select 8, '2013-08-16', 4, 4, 40
union
--not expired/status=40 single entry
select 9, '2013-08-16', 5, 5, 40
union
--expired/status=40 single entry
select 10, '2013-08-13', 6, 6, 40


/* scenarios:
not expired/status=40 and not status=40 entries - sees both     - userid = 1
not expired/status=40 and status=40 entries     - sees both     - userid = 2
expired/status=40 and not status=40 entries     - sees both     - userid = 3
expired/status=40 and status=40 entries         - sees single   - userid = 4
not expired/status=40 single entry                  - sees single   - userid = 5
expired/status=40 single entry                      - sees single   - userid = 6
*/
```

I'm not even sure it is possible to refactor this. Anyone with any ideas how to improve this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

John

Comment: initial data and expected data before and after query run would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
;with cte as (
    select ID, ExpiryDate, userid, siteid, Status,
        notExp = case when ExpiryDate > getdate() then 1 end,
        notExp_st40 = sum(case when ExpiryDate > getdate() and Status = 40 then 1 end) over()
    from @test2 
    where userid = @userid
)
select ID, ExpiryDate, userid, siteid, Status
from cte
where notExp=1 or notExp_st40 is NULL
```

Comment: what is the significance of over() after the sum?

Comment: `over()` after the sum allows calculating sum over a subset of rows (see [here (Example B in the Examples section)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).) Nothing inside parentheses after the `over` clause means that sum over _all_ rows is calculated. So, in this case sum is calculated and attached to every row as an additional column without the need in using `group by` so that rows can then be filtered by this column.